# Android - If doesn't work i am getting string from text box

Tags: android

if condition doesn't validate the value inside string mentioned below.

```
  //getting input box value
   newText = input.getText().toString();

  //using if condition newText got value "a"

    if (newText=="a")
    {
    //do something
    }
```

but the above if condition doesn't work i check string got right value which is a.

thanks in advance

Comment: Search well before post the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you should use `equals` method to compare the **values** of strings:

```
if ("a".equals(newText)) {
   //do something
}
```

To compare the references you can use `==`. For more information check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/3225458

Comment: You can also Android Internal Utility for it. It's TextUtils. For eg. TextUtils.equal("hello", "hello").